# Riemann metric: Universal Manifold Approximation (UMAP) and what is meant by a locally varying Riemann metric

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

I have been looking at the [Universal Manifold Approximation (UMAP)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03426v1.pdf) method for dimensional reduction or manifold learning in machine learning. The idea is to learn some lower dimensional manifold embedded within a higher dimensional ambient space. The method seems to proceed by the usual exploration of local embedding.

The one confusing thing is that the paper uses a bit of Riemann Geometry to suggest that a Riemann metric can vary locally on the manifold. Here is an excerpt from some of the documentation from the software package.

[image]

So it looks like the authors are creating simplices from the radius of balls about each point. And that at some points the ball has a larger radius than at other points. It seems that the basis of the metric is the nearest 1 neighbor, so the ball will grow until it finds that first nearest neighbhor.

I was hoping someone could explain what it means that a Riemann metric can "vary" over the manifold. I am not clear on what that means or how that works. So a metric is defined on the manifold, but that distance metric can change based upon where on the manifold it is applied?
Is there any intuition or bounds on this kind of idea. I imagine if the metric varies too much, then the manifold could just extend to cover $R^n$, without some limits.

UPDATE:

Here is some additional text from the paper.

[image]

Comment: Could it be that they're simply referring to the varying of the scalar product of the tangent spaces (which of course are all part of a single, fixed Riemannian metric)?

Comment: @Danu thanks for the comment. I can add some more detail from the paper to the question. I can update the post with some text from the paper, but this is what it seems like they are doing. So if you sampled points uniformly from the manifold, then each ball would be the same radius and contain roughly the same number of points. So instead what the authors do is take the distance to the first neighbor, and then use that to normalize the radius of the ball.

Comment: (con't) Since the first neighbor for each point can fall different distances apart, by normalizing the radius by the distance to the first neighbor, all of the balls are the same length essentially. haha, that is kinda an interesting trick, but I can't tell whether it seems like a legit thing or not from a differential topology standpoint :).

Answer (score 1):

What we call a metric in Riemannian geometry and differential geometry is actually a metric tensor field that changes at every point of the manifold (smoothly) and induces an inner product where you can then use to calculate norms, distances and geodesics. It is in this sense that it "varies".